# Vim in tmux display wrong colors

Tags: vim, tmux

I installed Ubuntu 11.10. Then downloaded Solarized theme for Gnome Terminal. From terminal my vim looks good: plugin vim-powerline displays correctly and syntax is highlighted with proper colors. But when I run tmux and there run vim - syntax highlight uses only one basic color and vim-powerline displays no colors. I looked at the FAQ on vim-powerline and solution should be this line in .tmux-config:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

But it doesn't work. I looked at TERM and it's return 'xterm' so I tried:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

But this also dosen't help.

This is the only line in .tmux.config. In .vimrc I have following lines:

```
call pathogen#infect()
set nocompatible
set encoding=utf-8
set laststatus=2
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
set t_Co=256
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorsheme solarized
```

Comment: No idea why you got no upvotes, not even from those who must have benefited by getting upvotes from their own answers. +1 from me. The question is sound and it helped me solve my own problem, too, by finding it.

Answer (score 63):

Starting tmux with the following flag fixes this for me:

```
tmux -2
```

from tmux man page:

-2            Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours.

Comment: Good hint. When the Cygwin version of screen started to crash vim I switched back to tmux again very quickly. Love it.

Comment: FYI - This was the only thing that worked for me with tmux 2.3 and the latest powerline. Colors in vim and tmux status bar were really weird.

Answer (score 38):

this worked for me

in `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

in `.vimrc`

```
set term=screen-256color
```

remove old term value for .vimrc, 
believe me this will work

Comment: Doesn't work for me. tmux 1.8, vim 7.4.1816, ubuntu x86_64 with kernel 3.13.0-92-generic. FYI.

Comment: It worked for me without .vimrc settings, only .tmux.conf.

Comment: The .tmux.conf setting did the trick for me!

Answer (score 33):

I am having the same problem on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS using Byobu 5.17 & tmux 1.5 using the latest Solarized from the GitHub repo.

I was able to partially fix this by specifying `$TERM` in the `.bashrc` file:

`export TERM="xterm-256color"`

It seems, also, that there is a bug filed on launchpad, but it is not yet resolved:
[byobu not displaying dircolors properly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/817690)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: Also worked on *Ubuntu 14.04* with *tmux 2.0*

Comment: This is the solution on OS X as well haha

Answer (score 8):

To me it looks like nobody knows what is talking about...

---

### How does our opening procedure works:

1. open a terminal *(whichever)*
2. open a `tmux`
3. open `vim`/`nvim`

---

### 1 Terminal

Open a terminal *(whichever you use - I use `st`)* and write a command:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> echo $TERM

st-256color
```

As answer I got a string `st-256color` because this string is compiled as the C string literal `termname` in the `st` *(check [here](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/config.def.h.html#l77))*. It is similar with whichever terminal you use. Somewhere in the binary there is a string literal that is set as a enviromental variable `TERM` when terminal is started.

Here you can't do anything but to remember this string.

---

### 2 Tmux

Now lets continue the chain...  `tmux` is opened **after** your terminal. In configuration file `~/.tmux.conf` I must now first make sure to identify enviromental variable `TERM` that my terminal set. So I write like this:

```
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",st*:Tc"
```

This line checks if enviromental variable `$TERM` starts with `st` *(therefore `st*`)* and makes sure to use true color (`Tc`) because current *"indexed colors"* *(8 bits = 2^8 = 256 colors)* is not enough for us. We want `tmux` to use *"true colors"* *(24 bits = 2^24 = 16777215 colors)*. Here we could add some more lines just to be sure we will match the value of `TERM`. In my case the below line also works because it searches for `256col` in the middle of `TERM`:

```
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
```

And if I would use `xfce4-terminal` that sets `TERM = xterm-256color` I could use a line like this instead:

```
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
```

So far `tmux` is covered. But before we continue the chain, we must make sure that `tmux` as well will export it's enviromental variable `TERM`.

In this case we can set it to whatever we want using this line inside the `~/.tmux.config`:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

Now make sure to exit the `tmux` and kill it's server:

```
tmux kill-server
```

Then enter `tmux` by using command `tmux` and execute command:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> echo $TERM

tmux-256color
```

You should get answer `tmux-256color`. Now we can continue to `vim`...

---

### 3 Vim

In our final step we just have to configure `vim` by adding this line inside it's configuration file `~/.vimrc`:

```
if exists('+termguicolors') && ($TERM == "st-256color" || $TERM == "tmux-256color")
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    set termguicolors
endif
```

This properly sets escape sequences `&t_8f` and `&t_8b` and finally sets *"true colors"* inside `vim`. But this is done only if `TERM` value is:

- `st-256color` *(when I open `vim` directly in the `st` terminal without opening `tmux` prior to that)*
- `tmux-256color` *(when I open `vim` while already in `tmux`)*

If you are using multiple terminals, here you should add them like this:

```
if exists('+termguicolors') && ($TERM == "st-256color" || $TERM == "tmux-256color" || $TERM == "xterm-256color")
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    set termguicolors
endif
```

Otherwise colors will not work across all the terminals... Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Terminal type should be set to screen-256color in ~/.tmux.conf. It tells tmux what to set the TERM evironment variable, so it won't work for the current session - start a new one and test then.

If it still doesn't work, you can run Vim using:

```
TERM=screen-256color vi
```

This sets the environment variable just for a one-off vi execution.

If that doesn't make vim display all the colours, test if your terminal (I'm not sure if you're testing with just one terminal emulator) is compiled to support the 256 colour palette - download and run the below Perl script from the terminal emulator in question.

http://scie.nti.st/dist/256colors2.pl

PS. I assume you've already corrected the typo jordanbrock noticed.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Marcin Kaminski, if `TERM=screen-256color vim <filename>`  works for you then just add following to your `.bashrc`

```
TERM=screen-256color
```

and following in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

I had the same problemd, this works for me.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me (tmux 1.8).

Comment: Actually, I just tested, and only changing `TERM=screen-256color` was enough for me, independently of setting tmux to `screen-256color` or to `xterm-256color`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the last line of your `.vimrc`.

It should be `colorscheme solarized`

Not sure if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be having the same problem documented in [this](https://superuser.com/a/399326/72210) answer.

Basically, .tmux.conf setting works, and `TERM` is set to `screen-256color`, but then tmux opens bash and calls your .bashrc, which sets `TERM` to something else (perhaps `xterm-256color`).

The solution is to set `TERM` in your terminal settings rather than in .bashrc. If that's not an option, you can check `TERM`inside .bashrc and not change it if it's already `screen-256color`.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell starting tmux, check that `$TERM` is either `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color`. See [how to change $TERM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#TERM_Environmental_Variable):

- Usually change `~/.Xresources` is the best way (if supported)
- For *gnome-terminal* see https://askubuntu.com/a/379472

As an alternative, as [Holy Mackerel](https://askubuntu.com/a/350604/172958) said, you can force tmux to 256color via:

```
$ tmux -2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solucion][1]
that may disturb your vision and make Vim unpleasant to use for an extended period of time.

You can fix this by running :set term=screen-256color in Vim or by relaunching Vim under the TERM=screen-256color environment, as some experts recommend: http://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html

Comment: What do you mean by [Solucion][1]? Were you trying to refer or link to another answer? Answers don't always appear in the same order. I recommend expanding this to clarify what you're saying may "disturb your vision and make Vim unpleasant to use for an extended period of time."

Answer (score 0):

In your .bashrc or .zshrc just add

```
if [[ $TERM == xterm ]]; then
    TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

and also start with the tmux -2

Answer (score 0):

For those, who is consuming time on colors, and if solarized vim doesn’t work on tmux, 
or tired of finding colors of vim, 
this should work in a minute, also it is from the official repository as follow.

```
yum install vim-jellybeans
```

or

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
cd ~/.vim/colors
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim/master/colors/jellybeans.vim
touch ~/.vimrc 
sed -i '/colorscheme/d' ~/.vimrc
echo colorscheme jellybeans >> ~/.vimrc
```

this will fix it with the beautiful color set and patterns are so focused and useful, if you are also tried to set those highlight, search words, this is it. everything has already set to use. You can even change colors in the configuration file.

**If you don't want to install anything but just simple quick solution,
ignore above and try this in vim**

`:colo ron`
you can also replace 'ron' with the following sets and even restore to `solo default`

```
blue 
darkblue 
default
delek
desert
elflord
evening
koehler
morning.vim
murphy
pablo
peachpuff
ron
shine
slate
torte
zellner
```

and save in .vimrc

```
colo ron
syntax on
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Before:

[image: Before]

#### After:

[image: After]

For me the problem was caused by these lines I had from `macos` based `.vimrc`.

```
set t_ZH=^[[3m
set t_ZR=^[[23m
set termguicolors
```

As soon as I commented out these 3 vim colors got back to normal in Ubuntu.