# Gnome-Terminal reports $TERM to be `xterm`

Tags: gnome-terminal

On a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10, the default gnome-terminal is reporting $TERM to be xterm where it should really be reporting xterm-256color. What is the best way of changing this? I'm avoiding putting this in my .bashrc as that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Care to explain why xterm is wrong? Afaik we all have xterm. Besides that: also care to explain why putting this in bashrc is asking for trouble?

Comment: `xterm` is wrong because most applications won't work in 256-color mode unless it's `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color` (vim and tmux being the main ones I care about).  Like @Freddy I would prefer not to set these in my shell profile, because I may be connecting from a different terminal type over SSH, and because it's really the terminal emulator's job to set this.  I'm amazed that gnome-terminal doesn't provide multiple emulations.

Comment: vte-0.40 (which will probably appear in Ubuntu 15.10) changed the default to `xterm-256colors`.

Answer (score 20):

You were well advised not to change your startup scripts, specially `~/.bashrc`. Any "terminal detection" using current `$TERM` or `$COLORTERM` in `~/.profile` is merely a guess, and may, as you said, cause trouble when using other terminals (say, Putty or xterm). The terminal emulator is supposed to set `$TERM`, and this should *not*  be changed from within the shell.

Gnome terminal, AFAIK, does not offer a configuration to change its `TERM`, but it does allow you to change your startup command, and that's all you need. Here is the trick:

```
Profile Preferences => Title and Command => Run a custom command instead of my shell
```

Then use the following command:

```
env TERM=xterm-256color /bin/bash
```

Just replace `/bin/bash` with your preferred shell if it's different. And no, you can't use `"$SHELL"` in that line for shell auto-detection ;) You have to hard-code it

Comment: There is an option in those settings to "When Command Exits:." The options are "Exit the Terminal," "restart the command," and " hold the terminal open." Which should I select?

Comment: @CalebJay: whichever you prefer, that option is not related to terminal colors. What to do when the command ends is purely a matter of preference.

Answer (score 12):

For connecting with a terminal that's not able to do 256 colors.

It'd be far better to detect the terminal specifically with `$COLORTERM`. Look for gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal, etc, and *then* set the `$TERM` variable to `xterm-256color`.

I do it with:

```
if [ "$COLORTERM" = "gnome-terminal" ] || [ "$COLORTERM" = "xfce4-terminal" ]
then
    export TERM=xterm-256color
elif [ "$COLORTERM" = "rxvt-xpm" ]
then
    export TERM=rxvt-256color
fi
```

Comment: Just be aware that Gnome Terminal from 3.13 onwards do not set `COLORTERM` anymore.

Comment: For versions that no longer set `COLORTERM` you can rely on `VTE_VERSION`.

Answer (score 6):

While it's true that terminfo has xterm+256color (`/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color`), termcap has just xterm (`/usr/share/vte/termcap/xterm`), so changing `$TERM` shouldn't be advisable.

Anyhow, `$TERM` is not set by gnome-terminal, but by vte. The default value for that environment variable can be changed either at compile time (giving an option to the configure script) or by calling the `vte_pty_set_term()` function. Looking at the sources of gnome-terminal, I see that `vte_pty_set_term` gets never called, so I can say that there are no ways to modify `$TERM` by editing gnome-terminal's settings.

What you have to do is to place the following piece of code in your `~/.profile`:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]
then
    export TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

Comment: `==` is a bash-only syntax, do not use it for snippets intended to be sourced by `sh` (which is the case with `~/.profile` in DEs). Also, the "x$.." syntax is not needed as you are correctly quoting the var expansion.

Comment: @MestreLion: feel free to edit my question.

Comment: I tried, but AU requires changes to be more than 6 chars, hence the comment

Comment: It does not work,the value set in .profile gets overridden.

Comment: @Hibou57: something is resetting it. Run `bash -xi` to see what is going on